# Let $G=(X\cup Y,E)$ bipartite, such that for every $A\subseteq X$ $\lvert A\rvert\leq \lvert\Gamma(A)\rvert$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(X\cup Y,E)$ such that for every $A\subseteq X$ $\lvert A\rvert\leq \lvert\Gamma(A)\rvert$, where $\Gamma$ is the number of neighbours. Prove that exists a match that sturates $X$.
I tried assuming for contradiction that exists $u\in X$ without a match. That brought me to a sort of loop- if there is no match for $u$ and $u$ must have at least 1 neighbour $v\in Y$ then it's because there exists $u'\in X$ that is matched with $v$. But thats not the way to prove something and its very messi.
Any ideas?

Comment: See Hall's Marriage Theorem.

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Nop. Halls marriage theorm is similar but the difference is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Well.. It is. Since English isnt my first language, my wikipedia didnt have this :P thanks.